# Displaying all images saved to a folder locally to individual div using JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Just want to ask this (please do note that I am new in programming and only practice during my free time)

1. I have 10 images saved locally to a folder (named "designImages") within my project folder
2. How can I display all the images within that folder to an individual div in the HTML using JSON (and javscript if needed)?

I tried fixing this but to no avail. The div just shows a text string in the front end.

JSON format and JS
Here is my code (tried to show 1 just to test):

```
let images = {
  id: "1",
  name: "Design 1",
  imageUrl: "/design-images/1.png",
};

let output = document.getElementById("myImage");
output.innerHTML = images.imageUrl;
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="myImage">
</body>
```

Here is my practice website: You can view the problem when you scroll down to the **See My Works!** section.
https://vladesplana.web.app/

Comment: A URL by itself does not create an image, you need to create an `<img>` element and assign the URL to it's `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
const images =[        // you have to create 10 objs instead of two

{
  id: "1",
  name: "Design 1",
  imageUrl: "/design-images/1.png",
},{
  id: "2",
  name: "Design 2",
  imageUrl: "/design-images/2.png",
};
]

const imagesOnSingleDiv=images.map(img=> `<img src=${img.imageUrl} alt=${img.name}>`).join("\n")
let output = document.getElementById("myImage");
output.innerHTML=imagesOnSingleDiv
```

The `imagesOnSingleDiv` contains the content for the `output`

Comment: Thank you so much, @aravind ks

but can you elaborate more on this part?

const imagesOnSingleDiv=images.map(img=> `<img src=${img.imageUrl} alt=${img.name}>`).join("\n")

Comment: Of course. Basically, we created an array of objects with each obj containing the data about images. ```map``` is an array method that returns a new array. the parameter ```img``` holds the current object in your images array. Here, we returned an array of ``img```tags which holds your images . Also, they are comma-separated. by using the join("\n") we can join all the array elements by a newline character and it will return a string which we can use for the ```innerHTML```.Hope it makes sense :)

Comment: Oh I got it now. But just for clarification, is the **img** parameter within the map method can be called anything? like **image** for example BUT still return the same **<img>** tags?

Comment: yup , you can rename the parameter ```img``` to anything and still got the same result

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon,
First, you should close your `<div>` tag :)

Then, you should add an `<img>` tag to your HTML. You can do it using HTML but then, you will not be able to auto-add new images inserted in your folder.

I suggest doing the following in javascript:

```js
let myDiv = document.getElementById("myImage");
let img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = images.imageUrl;
myDiv.appendChild(img);
```

First line gets your div in a variable ; second line creates a new image element ; third line puts the source for your image in it and the last line adds the image element to your html as a child of your div.

I hope this is clear enough to help you fix your code.

All best,
Benjamin